# Toast Notification in Windows 10 Action Center shows greyed out or deactivated

Tags: c#, windows, wcf, windows-services, toast

I have a problem when a project that send toast notifications to Windows 10 but when is showed in Action Center looks grayed out as the following image

[image: Notification Grayed out]

I create a Visual Studio solution that consists in a Windows service that contains a WCF project, and in the WCF project I create a toast notification that is persisted in Windows Action Center. This project (WCF project) has the functionality of create a shortcut that associate an ID for the app and I registered with the following command in Windows Registry

```
Set-ItemProperty "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Notifications\Settings\MyWCFWinServiceApp" -Name "ShowInActionCenter" -Type Dword -Value "1"
```

Like some tutorials indicate, I use ShellHelper class as it follows

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell.PropertySystem;
using MS.WindowsAPICodePack.Internal;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace apns_user_notification_receiver.ShellHelpers {
    internal enum STGM : long {
        STGM_READ = 0x00000000L,
        STGM_WRITE = 0x00000001L,
        STGM_READWRITE = 0x00000002L,
        STGM_SHARE_DENY_NONE = 0x00000040L,
        STGM_SHARE_DENY_READ = 0x00000030L,
        STGM_SHARE_DENY_WRITE = 0x00000020L,
        STGM_SHARE_EXCLUSIVE = 0x00000010L,
        STGM_PRIORITY = 0x00040000L,
        STGM_CREATE = 0x00001000L,
        STGM_CONVERT = 0x00020000L,
        STGM_FAILIFTHERE = 0x00000000L,
        STGM_DIRECT = 0x00000000L,
        STGM_TRANSACTED = 0x00010000L,
        STGM_NOSCRATCH = 0x00100000L,
        STGM_NOSNAPSHOT = 0x00200000L,
        STGM_SIMPLE = 0x08000000L,
        STGM_DIRECT_SWMR = 0x00400000L,
        STGM_DELETEONRELEASE = 0x04000000L,
    }

    internal static class ShellIIDGuid {
        internal const string IShellLinkW = "000214F9-0000-0000-C000-000000000046";
        internal const string CShellLink = "00021401-0000-0000-C000-000000000046";
        internal const string IPersistFile = "0000010b-0000-0000-C000-000000000046";
        internal const string IPropertyStore = "886D8EEB-8CF2-4446-8D02-CDBA1DBDCF99";
    }

    [ComImport,
    Guid(ShellIIDGuid.IShellLinkW),
    InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    internal interface IShellLinkW {
        UInt32 GetPath(
            [Out(), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] StringBuilder pszFile,
            int cchMaxPath,
            //ref _WIN32_FIND_DATAW pfd,
            IntPtr pfd,
            uint fFlags);
        UInt32 GetIDList(out IntPtr ppidl);
        UInt32 SetIDList(IntPtr pidl);
        UInt32 GetDescription(
            [Out(), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] StringBuilder pszFile,
            int cchMaxName);
        UInt32 SetDescription(
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszName);
        UInt32 GetWorkingDirectory(
            [Out(), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] StringBuilder pszDir,
            int cchMaxPath
            );
        UInt32 SetWorkingDirectory(
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszDir);
        UInt32 GetArguments(
            [Out(), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] StringBuilder pszArgs,
            int cchMaxPath);
        UInt32 SetArguments(
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszArgs);
        UInt32 GetHotKey(out short wHotKey);
        UInt32 SetHotKey(short wHotKey);
        UInt32 GetShowCmd(out uint iShowCmd);
        UInt32 SetShowCmd(uint iShowCmd);
        UInt32 GetIconLocation(
            [Out(), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] out StringBuilder pszIconPath,
            int cchIconPath,
            out int iIcon);
        UInt32 SetIconLocation(
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszIconPath,
            int iIcon);
        UInt32 SetRelativePath(
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszPathRel,
            uint dwReserved);
        UInt32 Resolve(IntPtr hwnd, uint fFlags);
        UInt32 SetPath(
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszFile);
    }

    [ComImport,
    Guid(ShellIIDGuid.IPersistFile),
    InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    internal interface IPersistFile {
        UInt32 GetCurFile(
            [Out(), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] StringBuilder pszFile
        );
        UInt32 IsDirty();
        UInt32 Load(
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszFileName,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] STGM dwMode);
        UInt32 Save(
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszFileName,
            bool fRemember);
        UInt32 SaveCompleted(
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszFileName);
    }
    [ComImport]
    [Guid(ShellIIDGuid.IPropertyStore)]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    interface IPropertyStore {
        UInt32 GetCount([Out] out uint propertyCount);
        UInt32 GetAt([In] uint propertyIndex, out PropertyKey key);
        UInt32 GetValue([In] ref PropertyKey key, [Out] PropVariant pv);
        UInt32 SetValue([In] ref PropertyKey key, [In] PropVariant pv);
        UInt32 Commit();
    }


    [ComImport,
    Guid(ShellIIDGuid.CShellLink),
    ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    internal class CShellLink { }

    public static class ErrorHelper {
        public static void VerifySucceeded(UInt32 hresult) {
            if (hresult > 1) {
                throw new Exception("Failed with HRESULT: " + hresult.ToString("X"));
            }
        }
    }
   }
```

And the class that I create the toast notification is coded as this

```
using System;
using Windows.Data.Xml.Dom;
using Windows.UI.Notifications;
using Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications;
using Microsoft.QueryStringDotNET;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace apns_user_notification_receiver
{
    class ToastNotificationGenerator {
        private const String APP_ID = "MyWinServiceWCFApp";

        public void GenerateNotification(string Title, string Content) {
            XmlDocument toastXml = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(ToastTemplateType.ToastImageAndText04);
            XmlNodeList stringElements = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");
            stringElements[0].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode("Notifications"));
            stringElements[1].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode(Title));
            stringElements[2].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode(Content));
            ToastNotification toast = new ToastNotification(toastXml);
            ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier(APP_ID).Show(toast);
        }

        public void GenerateNotificationUWP() {
            // In a real app, these would be initialized with actual data
            string title = "Andrew sent you a picture";
            string content = "Check this out, Happy Canyon in Utah!";
            int conversationId = 384928;
            // Construct the visuals of the toast
            ToastVisual visual = new ToastVisual()
            {
                BindingGeneric = new ToastBindingGeneric() {
                    Children = {
            new AdaptiveText() {
                Text = title,
                HintStyle = AdaptiveTextStyle.Title
            },
            new AdaptiveText() {
                Text = content,
                HintStyle = AdaptiveTextStyle.Title
            }
            }
                }
            };

            ToastContent toastContent = new ToastContent() {
                Visual = visual,
                // Arguments when the user taps body of toast
                Launch = new QueryString() {
            { "action", "viewConversation" },
            { "conversationId", conversationId.ToString() }
        }.ToString()
            };

            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(toastContent.GetContent());
            // And create the toast notification
            var toast = new Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotification(doc);
            ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier(APP_ID).Show(toast);
        }
    }
}
```

Someone who knows why is this happening? 
I suspect it has something to do with the activations that notification can receive.
Thanks

Comment: Have you found solution for the issue?